# PHP Function Executing During Parsing / Interpretation?

Tags: php

I have a simple function that toggles an ON/OFF 1 bit column in a table that I know works correctly, but seems to be executing twice.

```
// toggleFunction($variable) toggles the value and returns the new result
// and is placed BEFORE the EXIT to see what value it returns.  It is ommitted in the
// second block below because I only want it to run once, and then EXIT through    
// showPage();

// #1
// TOGGLES ONCE CORRECTLY BUT THE PAGE IS NOT DISPLAYED BECAUSE IT DOES NOT REACH
// showPage();

...
if(isset($variable))   
{   
    var_dump($class->toggleFunction($variable));
    EXIT;
    $user_data = $class->toggleFunction($variable);
    $class->showPage($user_data);
}


// #2
// APPEARS TO TOGGLE TWICE AND DISPLAYS INCORRECT VALUE ON PAGE

...
if(isset($variable))   
{
    $user_data = $class->toggleFunction($variable);
    $class->showPage($user_data);
}


function showPage($user_data)
{
       echo $user_data;
       EXIT;
}

function toggleFunction($id)
{
   try{
     $array = array($id);
     $query = "UPDATE table SET ONOFF = ONOFF XOR 1 WHERE id=?;";
     $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
     $stmt->execute($array);

     $query = "SELECT ONOFF FROM table WHERE id=?;";
     $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
     $stmt->execute($array);
     $result = $statement->fetchAll();
     return $result;
   }
   catch{
    ... }
}
```

Debugging:  Placing var_dump()'s and exit's has revealed that the correct value is obtained without any html formatting, but then the page appears to refresh (even though there are absolutely no refreshes called) and the incorrect (original) value before  toggling appears.  I think this is because it is updating the value twice (changes it back and forth) and so there appears to be no change.  Other debugging techniques revealed that the function works normally during a refresh of the page after the first toggle has been attempted and failed.

Last Mention: My knowledge of the parsing and execution stages (allocating memory, assigning variables, etc.) is low to mediocre. I have noticed this before during other web-scripting activities but have never found out why it seems to be actually executing the code during the first pass. Originally, this led me to place multiple isset() blocks to make sure the $_GET and other variables were actually present, but that does not seem to be the problem here.  I am also using include_once()'s at the beginning of my scripts when necessary.

Comment: Post your code. If you're saying the action that `toggleFunction()` is supposed to perform is performed twice, anyone who wants to help you will need to know what `toggleFunction()` is doing.

Comment: I figured too much code would only confuse. Will edit.

Comment: Also, it would help to post actual code, rather than "test" code (which wouldn't even parse; you're missing an = in there) and explain the input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: I am not so concerned about the actual code, as I have other bits like this that function normally. As someone trying to help me, I understand that you are.  This is a small cog in a much larger wheel and I am pretty sure that the query is being executed during a call to include_once().  Much like try{ var_dump($_GET['variable']); } without a check for isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['variable']) may render an error during parsing if included as a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to to come back and close this:

Learned from my previous mistakes and was able to restore a backup that did not contain this error.  Most likely cause was a syntax error that was causing the script to be executed in a manner other than intended.  Would have liked to have found the root cause to be sure it does not happen again, but too much time has already been spent on this problem to spend any further.

For future travelers: be sure to check that your variables are in fact set before trying to use them.  Also, for WebDev using separate template scripts, ensure that your script is clearly calling exits after echoing out the desired HTML.  Otherwise, it will return and continue executing if your control blocks are not configured correctly.

Comment: Instead of backups, use a version control system to easily see the differences between different versions of your code!

Comment: Yes, I believe that would be the next step up! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
  exit;
```

**immediately terminates the PHP script** emitting just the stuff, that has already been generated using `echo` or `print`.

In you case `exit;` terminates the script using no output.

Comment: I understand the EXIT; terminates the script.  I put it there so that I could see what the value of the var_dump(); on the first go-around which is correct. If the EXIT is not there, the script seems to execute twice and the correct value is replaced with the incorrect one and passed to showPage().

Comment: As of the time I wrote my comment, no var_dump() was before the exit;